# How to add rows in excel depending on the value of cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want the user to write the required number of rows in a cell, and based on this cell value that many numbers of blank rows should be generated somewhere else in the excel sheet.

Basically, I want to create something like a table and based on the number in the cell, that many blank rows would be created for the user to fill.

Suppose the value of the cell is 0 and I change it to 5. Based on this change, 5 rows would be added between the top and bottom row that I can fill with data.

[I want the data to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maP01.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about how the rows should be?

Comment: This is likely to require VBA.  The "fundamental premise" of Excel is that a formula tells a cell how to retrieve or calculate its *own* value, not how to "project" a value elsewhere.  Excel formulas generally "pull" and in this case you want to "push" and that usually involves a procedural language like VBA.  The newer array functions stretch that "pull" concept, but generally still assume that the cell in question is one of the cells being affected.

Comment: I have a provided a sample of what I want and I have also filled these rows. Let me know if you need me to explain it even further